# "Current time" incorrect in ExpandedController for live streams

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

As you can see on following capture, the current time is incorrect for live streams. How can I overload or hide it ?

[image]

Comment: Can you share the stream?

Comment: Sorry I can't and it won't work outside the country.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if currentTime in the receiver (just for live content) is expressed as Unix epoch time. If so you just need to convert it to a valid value. 
Try this on the receiver:

```
var now = new Date();       
var timenow = new Date(now).getTime() / 1000;               
var seektime = timenow - requestData.currentTime();
requestData.currentTime(requestData.duration() - seektime);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following workaround on the receiver side: I send "0" as duration if the value is too high. It's not clean and the counter progress on sender side, but if someone have a better idea why the receiver has incorrect time in Live stream, you're welcome !

```
playerManager.setMessageInterceptor(cast.framework.messages.MessageType.MEDIA_STATUS, initTextType);

function initTextType(requestData) { 
    // update stream current time if LIVE
    if (requestData.currentTime > 18000) {
      requestData.currentTime = 0;
      console.log('~> adjust current time for LIVE streams');
    }
}
```